# Optimization - For statement and variable declarations

Tags: javascript, loops, scope

Here is a quotation [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Syntax) about 'for' statement :

> An expression (including assignment expressions) or variable
>   declaration. Typically used to initialize a counter variable. This
>   expression may optionally declare new variables with the var keyword.
>   **These variables are not local to the loop**, i.e. they are in the same
>   scope the for loop is in. The result of this expression is discarded.

So when I write this kind of code :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

At each iteration of the outer loop I declare the variable j, which was already declared right ?

So is it better to write something like this :

```
for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

... or we do not care?

Comment: As long as you declare it within the same function scope, it doesn't matter. If you declare it at the for loop, it helps to show your intention to only use it within the for loop though. So I would go with option 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior this quote refers to is called **hoisting** and is important to know in JavaScript.

Here's how [the MDN explains it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting):

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are
>   processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere
>   in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means
>   that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This
>   behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable
>   declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

The reason you don't declare all your variables at the top of the function, is because their **localization** makes the code clearer.

There's **absolutely no gain** in having both vars being declared in the first loop. It's only confusing. It's the same for the JS engine, but the other developers reading this code will wonder why `j` is declared at an unexpected location.

Now, if you're disturbed by the fact your variable exists before (with an `undefined` value) and after the loop where you use it, rejoice: there's a new declaration type coming with ES6: `let`, which scopes the variable to the block.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Beware: compatibility of `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility)

For now, please use the standard form that everybody expects:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The **convention**, in such a case, is that `i` and `j` won't be used outside of 
their loop. When (and only in this case) you want to use `i` or `j` after (for example there's a break in the loop), use this:

```
var i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
// use i and j here
```

Comment: What about having two consecutive, not nested loops? I usually declare the i variable once at the beginning of the function in these cases

Comment: @Pablo I personally strongly prefer to repeat the `var` statement, even if useless: it's clearer and it prevents a bug the day somebody refactors and moves the first loop. Note that some linters are confused in such a case, though.

Comment: I was doing that, but I started to use JShint and it complains about duplicate declarations everywhere... nevertheless I reset the variable every time to avoid that bug